# How to get position of view during drag and drop in a GridView in Android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am working on `GridView`. It has 4 tiles with `ImageView` and `TextView`.
I want to implement Drag and Drop. When I used `DragEvent` I was able to drag the tile over one another.
But when I drop, I want to swap the images.
So I tried to use `gridView.getPositionForView(View v)`
But it gives me the position (ie 0)  of the **first tile** I tried to drag. 
then when I bring to **4th tile**, during the drop, I need the position of the drop tile. (i.e 4)

But I am not able to retrieve the position of the tile where I drop.  When ever I try to use `gridView.getPositionForView(View v)`

It gives me the first position of the tile that I started dragging.
Please help me get the position of the tile where I am going to drag and drop.

Comment: did you solve the problem?